# Mac: Import .p12 certificate into the Keychain via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, keychain, certificate

I'm trying to import .p12 certificate into the keychain on my Mac via bash script. So far, I've been trying:

1. `sudo security import` command.

It returns that import was successful but, in fact, it never gets imported into any keychain.

2. `sudo  security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.p12`

it throws the following error:

> Password: SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.

The only thing that worked for me was the .cer format via this command: `sudo security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.cer`. It does import the certificate into the keychain and I can see it in the keychain access.

But I only have .p12 certificates. Could anyone help me with that one, please?

Comment: Can .p12 certs be imported via the GUI Keychain Access app? If not, I agree with Robert Longson’s answer that converting with OpenSSL first is the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert a .p12 file to .cer via the [openssl pkcs12 command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html)

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.cer
```

Then import the .cer since you know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> Password: SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import

**SecCertificateCreateFromData** is actually deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396025-seccertificatecreatefromdata. Not sure why security tool would still use it.